# Writing in King James archaic language

Tags: grammar, writing-style, archaicisms

I'm currently working on an English project and I have chosen to rewrite a story (Heart of Darkness by Joseph Conrad) in a biblical, King James style. I have done a large amount of reading but I do sometimes get confused, especially on certain sentence structures. Do you have any tips on grammar, vocabulary, or sentence structure that will help me make my writing seem more authentic?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is about learning materials (please see the [help/on-topic] for details on what questions are considered on topic).

Comment: Keepest thou to the best-known words, and check euery sense, for the recent sense that is clear in the mind may be a greater noveltie than thou thinkest, and the anachronism goeth down like a lead zeppelin.

Comment: I would review questions tagged with [tag:early-modern-english] and [tag:shakespeare], and more distantly [tag:archaic] and [tag:literary-english] for some of the things to consider, from vocabulary differences to lost inflection.

Comment: Here's the [Project Gutenberg version](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/219/219-h/219-h.htm) of the text. If your 30,000-word rewriting project turns out not to be even more fraught with tribulation and vexation than Charles Marlow's quest up the Congo, I will be both impressed and astonished.

Answer (score 0):

*Heart of Darkness* is 30,000 words long.  Pick something shorter.

Although I rarely make this suggestion, read your Bible.  Here's the beginning bit:

> 1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.
>
> 2 And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the
>   face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the
>   waters.
>
> 3 And God said, Let there be light: and there was light.

Note the repetitive structure ("And... And.. And"), simple clauses, and use of groups of short words in place of more specific longer ones.

(And remember, the King James Version is called that because [King James](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_VI_and_I) commissioned the translation, not because he personally wrote or spoke like that.)

Comment: Or for the very first KJV, "In the beginning God created the Heauen, and the Earth. / And the earth was without forme, and voyd, and darkenesse was vpon the face of the deepe: and the Spirit of God mooued vpon the face of the waters. / And God said, Let there be light: and there was light." It depends on just how far back you want to go.

Comment: "Mooued"?  Is that like a cow's opinion, a mooued point?